# A weighted sum of independent Poisson random variables $X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3+\dots+nX_n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I have that for $1 \leq i \leq n$, the mutually independent random variables

$$X_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu_i)$$

Then what is the distribution of $$Y \sim \sum_{i=1}^{n}i X_i$$ It looks a bit like an expectation, so I am interested to know if anything is known about it? Otherwise, the best we can do to obtain $P(Y = k)$ is to sum over integer partitions of $k$ with part numbers which are Poissonly distributed with means $\mu_1, \mu_2,\dots$ etc?

Comment: We might hope to prove that it's not too far different from $\text{Poisson}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i \mu_i\right)$, on the principle that we're adding up $\binom n2$ Poisson variables, *many* of which are independent...

Comment: Because when you write $2X_1$ we can say this is the sum of two dependent Poissons, so $2X_1 = X_a + X_b$, but where $X_a=X_b$, and $X_a$ and $X_b$ are Poisson?

Comment: Right. Whenever we take $i X_i$, this is the sum of $i$ very-very-dependent Poisson variables, but each of the $\text{Poisson}(\mu_i)$'s we're adding is independent from at least $\binom{n-1}{2}$ of the other Poissons.

Comment: It is possible to compute the characteristic function of $jX_j$, hence that of $Y$: $$\varphi_Y(t)=\exp\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\mu_j\left(e^{itj}-1\right)\right)$$but it is not clear whether the distribution function admits a nice form, even in the case $\mu_j=1$ for each $j$.